# Messages of CEdit in visual C++6.0

Tags: c++, winforms, visual-c++, event-handling, focus

I have a `CDialog` contains many `CEdit` objects. They all have to do similar operations when kill focus (for example: when focus is killed the edit box text's is changed).

I can define the dialog's message map this way:

```
ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(ID1, kf1)
ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(ID2, kf2)
ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(ID3, kf3)
ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(ID4, kf4)
```

and all `kf` function will call a common function:

```
CommonFunction(CEdit* editBox)
```

But is there a way to transfer the edit box in the `kf` function itself? I mean to define it this way:

```
ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(ID1, kf(ID1))
ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(ID2, kf(ID2))
ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(ID3, kf(ID3))
ON_EN_KILLFOCUS(ID4, kf(ID4))
```

or another way.

**NOTE:** I use Visual C++ 6.0 ('98 edition)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ON_CONTROL_RANGE in the message map to dispatch all of the messages to the same function. To do this it is necessary to assure that the IDs are in a continuous range. (Edit resource.h if necessary.)

```
ON_CONTROL_RANGE(BN_CLICKED, IDC_RADIO_DRAWALL, IDC_RADIO_DRAWBEST, OnRadioBtnDraw)

void CVisualPPView::OnRadioBtnDraw(UINT nID)
{
}
```