# How to define IDs for ON_CONTROL_RANGE c++ MFC WINAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013, mfc

I'm comparatively new to MFC / C++ / WINAPI programming and currently I'm working on a project where I have to manage clicks of dynamically created Buttons.

I did quite a lot of research and found the following approach with ON_CONTROL_RANGE:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84xtde24.aspx

I even made it working but my solution is not yet satisfying considering to write nice and clean code.

My working solution:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CFooter, CWnd)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_WM_SIZE()
    ON_CONTROL_RANGE(BN_CLICKED, 2000, 2030, OnButtonClicked)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Handler Function in Class CFooter declared as:

```
afx_msg void OnButtonClicked(UINT nIDbutton){...}
```

With what I'm not happy yet is that my ID's are defined as raw integer numbers therefore I wanted to define values for them like:

```
#define IDC_FOOTER_FIRST_BUTTON_ID  2000;
#define IDC_FOOTER_LAST_BUTTON_ID  2030;

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CFooter, CWnd)
   ON_WM_PAINT()
   ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
   ON_WM_CREATE()
   ON_WM_SIZE()
   ON_CONTROL_RANGE(BN_CLICKED, IDC_FOOTER_FIRST_BUTTON_ID, IDC_FOOTER_LAST_BUTTON_ID, OnButtonClicked)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

But this will not compile anymore.. Why is that what am I missing out?
I tried to define the values in the header file outside of the class definition of CFooter and in the cpp file above the messagemap as shown.

The errors are kind of cryptic e.g.:

syntax error in line ON_CONTROL_RANGE ","
syntax error in line ON_CONTROL_RANGE "}"
_messageEntries: undeclared identifier
GetThisMessageMap: undeclared identifier

So I assume I'm not defining my IDs correctly / at the right spot.. 
Can someone give me an Explanation what I'm doing wrong and where / how to define the ID's correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just remove the semi-colon at the end: `#define IDC_FOOTER_FIRST_BUTTON_ID  2000` ...

Comment: Unless you need to use the symbolic constants in resource scripts, there is no need to use macros at all. Just declare regular numeric constants, e.g. `const int IDC_FOOTER_FIRST_BUTTON_ID = 2000;`.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thanks since I removed the semi-colon after #define it works like a charm ;)

Comment: @JanRaufelder Don't your buttons have ID constants anyway? If you #include resource.h then you can directly use the actual ID constants themselves for the range. That is what I do. Can I also kindly ask how you went about adding the ON_CONTROL_RANGE implementation? Was it all manually?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: The OP is using dynamically created controls. The auto-generated *resource.h* file is only updated when you have a resource script.

Comment: @IInspectable Ah, understood. I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Why don't you add it as an actual answer? Then it can be voted / accepted. :)

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: yes, you'll have to add ON_CONTROL_RANGE() manually in the message_map as well as the function(OnButtonClicked) that will handle the sent Message (BN_CLICKED) for the given ID-Range compare to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17206564/messages-of-cedit-in-visual-c6-0